# Convert USB Port to LPT1

Tags: usb, drivers, port, parallel-port

I have a GIF12 Card reader & software that connects to a computer via LPT1 port. I want to connect the card reader via a USB port. I need the computer to see the USB port as LPT1.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a USB to Parallel port adapter. Some adapters have a Centronics 36-pin plug, others have a DB25 plug on the end. Make sure you get one that your card reader will plug into, and make sure it is bi-directional.

Answer (score 0):

Most USB to parallel adapters are designed to send data to printers. As you want to read data from the card reader, you'll need to make sure the one you get is bi-directional. Here are some examples. Note that I have not tried any of them:

- http://www.jaycar.com.au/productView.asp?ID=XC4847
- http://www.ambery.com/hiusbpaprpoa.html
- http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812224011

You'll need to keep your fingers crossed and hope it will work. If at all possible, I would install a PCI parallel port card in the PC (not possible with laptops, of course).